# Big Sur keeps falling asleep while watching media (Netflix, Disney+, Youtube)

Tags: macos, safari, sleep-wake, video, big-sur

Ever since upgrading to Big Sur (11.0) and using Safari, Big Sur keeps falling asleep while watching media like Netflix, Disney+, or even Youtube. Not sure if Safari is at fault here, but I've made sure that my energy settings allow for the computer to stay awake.

Has anyone else come across this? Is there a way to reset power settings and avoid this?

EDIT: Happening with Chrome and Brave as well.

Comment: To make sure it is not Safari, try it in Chrome/Firefox/... and report back

Comment: @X_841 Happening with Chrome and Brave Chromium as well.

Comment: what about using the apps and not the browser?  You should be able to run the Netflix, Apple+ iOS apps natively on Big Sur.  Do they work and does your Mac still go to sleep?

Comment: I can try that but quiet simply my MBP never fell asleep during media on Catalina. This might be a bug I need to report.